# Can I subscribe to a variable being initialized?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I want to get notified when a specific variable gets initialized.

something like this.

```
var name;

// magic happens here
initialization(name).subscribe(_name => {...});

setTimeout(_ => {
  name = 'foo';
}, 1000);
```

Is there any known way to do this?

Comment: Can you narrow it down a bit? Why is it rxjs in tag? Strictly speaking there's no way to subscribe to plain var change, however there are ton of native ways, libraries etc to achieve the same behavior (Proxy or get/set from native javascript, `Backbone.Model` and rxjs are libraries for this)

Comment: Yes it was meant not to be specifically related to rxjs.. I thought rxjs maybe has a functionality for that.

Answer (score 1):

Closest is a BehaviorSubject, but you won't be able to use the syntax `name = 'foo'`;

```js
const name = new rxjs.BehaviorSubject(undefined);

name.subscribe(_name => { console.log(_name) });

setTimeout(() => {
  name.next('foo');
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setter` if you have no control over the functions that sets value to the `name` or if you simply want to avoid adding logic to every of those functions (if there are many of them):

```
const _subject = new Subject();
// keep good practise and do not subscribe to Subjects:
const observable$ = _subject.asObservable();

let _name;
set name(name) {
  _name = name;
  subject.next(name);
};

// also adding a getter in case you want to use 'name' somewhere else
get name() {
  return _name;
}

// magic happens here
observable$.subscribe(_name => {...});

setTimeout(_ => {
  name = 'foo';
}, 1000);
```

this will emit every time `name` gets a value, but you can for. ex. `pipe(take(1))` and it will emit only once - after `name` gets a value